# I can't control the video with the TrackBar1 scroller with vlc c#

Tags: c#, libvlcsharp

[this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znXvo.png)

I have tried  `axVLCPlugin21.input.time = trackBar1.Value;` but to no avail

code

```
private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            axVLCPlugin21.input.time = trackBar1.Value;
           
        }

        private void axVLCPlugin21_MediaPlayerTimeChanged(object sender, AxAXVLC.DVLCEvents_MediaPlayerTimeChangedEvent e)
        {
            lb_START.Text = TimeFormat(e.time);
            trackBar1.Value = e.time;
        }

        private void axVLCPlugin21_MediaPlayerPlaying(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lb_END.Text = TimeFormat((int)axVLCPlugin21.input.length);
            trackBar1.Maximum = (int)axVLCPlugin21.input.length;
        }
```

Comment: [Please do not post images of code because they are hard to use.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Code should be posted directly **as text** in your question.